# How to create a testimonials page using Orchard CMS?

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I am very new to Orchard CMS and I am working on trying to create a testimonials page in my project.

I have created a content type that holds a body, textfield (TestimonialBy), and tags (for SEO purposes) called Testimonial.  Now I need to create a page that will roll up all of my testimonials onto it.

I can create the content for the testimonial, and it is visible via navigating to the testimonial URL, however what I need to do now is create a testimonal page (localhost/testimonials) that will take ALL published testimonials and roll them up on one page so I could have:

Testimonial 1 content
-name of test giver

Testimonial 2 content
-name of test giver

etc

My question is, how do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create a content type like you've already done with the following parts:

- Title Part (if you want it to have a title)
- Autoroute Part (if you want it to have its own URL)
- Body (for content)
- Tags

Then enable the projector module.

Then create a query that lists your new content type.

Then create a new projection (or you can also use a projection widget) to show the content items returned by the query.

*Updated for Orchard 1.4+*

Answer (score 1):

You should start by reading the documentation at [Orchard Project](http://www.orchardproject.net/docs/), specifically the 'Extending Orchard' section which shows you how to create your own modules and content parts.

You could approach this in a few ways - one would be just edit the HTML of the page that has the testimonials and this is by far the quickest an easiest.

Another way might be to create a testimonial widget that lets you enter a name, quote, description etc. on the widget editor. You could then create a layer with the page's URL as part of the rule and just add widgets to the content zone. Because the widget would be driven by a content part, you could also add testimonials to your pages, blogs, custom content types etc.

Another way might be to write a controller for the admin interface that lets you do CRUD for testimonial records. You could then write a content part which lists these. You can then add this content part to a page, widget etc and with a bit of work add options so that you can control the testimonials that are shown on a per-content part basis.

Ultimately there are many ways to do this sort of thing in Orchard, it just depends on what you need and how much time/effort you want to put in to it.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Sounds very close to a blog post. You might be able to create a testimonials blog and fill out the posts with the testimonial content.

Or u could add the containable part to the testimonial contentType and add the testimonials to the list.

Hope that helps

Dan